# docker build command took all of the space

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I mistakenly ran, `docker build` command in a folder with a dockerfile, where there were few large folders with few hundred gigs of files.

```
folder_1 (55 gigs)
folder_2 (182 gigs)
kaldi_ub18_cuda10.Dockerfile
```

Inside this folder, I ran the command,
`nvidia-docker build -t nabil/kaldi_sre:ub18cu10 . -f kaldi_ub18_cuda10.Dockerfile`

After that, I got
`docker sending build context to docker daemon 91gb/237gb`

Unfortunately, I had only around 90 gigs free in my root `/`.

After that, the command stopped and it showed me not enough space.

Now, when I run `df -h --total`, I see my `/` has 0 space.

```
udev             94G     0   94G   0% /dev
tmpfs            19G  212M   19G   2% /run
/dev/sda6       1.7T  1.7T     0 100% /
tmpfs            94G  1.8G   92G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            94G     0   94G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1       1.8T  1.5T  213G  88% /home/tit/Data
/dev/sda1       453M  446M     0 100% /boot
tmpfs            19G   24K   19G   1% /run/user/108
tmpfs            19G     0   19G   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop3       27M   27M     0 100% /snap/heroku/4068
/dev/loop1       27M   27M     0 100% /snap/heroku/4076
/dev/loop2      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11743
/dev/loop4      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11798
total           3.8T  3.1T  549G  86% -
```

Output from `/var/lib/docker`

```
:/var/lib/docker$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 | sort
180K    ./network
182G    ./tmp
205G    ./overlay2
20K     ./builder
20K     ./plugins
386G    .
4.0K    ./runtimes
4.0K    ./swarm
4.0K    ./trust
509M    ./containers
53M     ./image
72K     ./buildkit
72K     ./volumes
```

I am not sure what happened that took all of my space. I tried `docker system prune`, but it didn't give me my space.

I can not restart the server as there are many apps running on it. How can I get the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files should be in `/var/lib/docker/tmp`. After removing files from this directory, I'd recommend restarting the docker engine (`systemctl restart docker`) in case the engine had open file handles to files in that directory, or anything running that expected files in there to exist.

If you're using buildkit, I'd also recommend:

```
docker builder prune
```

Comment: Thanks,  I tried builder prune, I didn't get any space back. There is around 180 gigs in my tmp inside `/var/lib/docker`. There are many docker containers running, I don't think I should restart it.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi the restart is a recommendation from me, but it may not be required. If you see some instability it would be a good first step before a reboot (which is generally recommended after filing root, daemons crash when they can't write to disk, and it's hard to know which ones).

Answer (score 1):

Running `docker system prune --all --force` is a good start ([documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)).

> As seen in comment, be aware it will delete docker images too.

Then, could you check your `/var/lib/docker/tmp` directory :

- Should be safe to clean its content.
- Requires root privileges
- Used during build process depending of your build context

  > with gigs of files in your case.
- If docker hold files in that directory :

```sh
# Assuming your system uses systemd
systemctl stop docker
rm -r /var/lib/docker/tmp/*
systemctl start docker
```

You may check available disk space like this :

```sh
cd /var/lib/docker
du -h --max-depth=1 | sort
```

Comment: Note, the `--all` will delete images, which could be an issue if you build and run images locally rather than only pulling from a registry.